# Перенос из "bat" в "py" скрипта выключения компьютера по таймеру

Tags: python, python-3.x, bat

Как грамотно адаптировать этот текст перенеся из `*.bat` в `*.py`. Моя главная проблема, как мне кажется заключается в правильном указании значений в `os.system`. Пробую писать что-то типа:

```
xx = input()
if xx >= 100 and xx <= 1000:
    os.system("shutdown -s -t xx")
```

или даже просто:

`os.system("shutdown -s -t 1000")`, а он все равно при запуске кода выключает компьютер сразу, какие бы значения не ставил.

содержание файла bat:

```
echo off
set /p answer="Выключить - 1, Отменить - 2: "
goto %answer%

:1
set /p min_off="Выключить компьютер через (минут): "
set /A sec_off="%min_off% * 60"
color C
echo Компьютер будет выключен через %min_off% минут
shutdown -s -f -t %sec_off%
TIMEOUT /T 3
exit

:2
color A
echo Запланированное завершение работы Windows отменено
shutdown -a
TIMEOUT /T 3
exit
```

Как его корректно написать в python?

Comment: По поводу `os.system("shutdown -s -t 1000")` - все нормально работает, мне компьютер сообщил, что выключится через 16 минут.

Comment: Все верно, спасибо за участие в вопросе. Была строка лишняя, по невнимательности не убрал. Она и отправляла постоянно в выключение компьютер после выполнения кода. Глупая ошибка, по невнимательности :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xx у вас в строке - это просто два символа x, никак не связанные с вашей переменной xx. Чтобы вместо xx подставлялось значение переменной, нужно использовать f-строки:

```
os.system(f"shutdown -s -t {xx}")
```

Обратите внимание на f перед строкой и фигурные скобки вокруг имени переменной.

Подробнее можно почитать здесь: [f-строки в Python](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings)

Comment: или даже просто:

os.system("shutdown -s -t 1000")

Comment: @eri это работает, я буквально только что это проверил. В комментарии к вопросу написал. Если у автора вопроса это не работает, значит он что-то не так делает.

Comment: @insolor Благодарю вас за помощь и ссылку на статью!